Why is implementing advertisement via Goodle Admob causing my app to crash on startup?
Im creating an app in Android Studio using Kotlin. Im following the guide on the Google Admob website in order to try and implement banner advertisement. Though no matter what I do, the app keeps crashing on launch after trying to add the advertisement.
Logcat shows the following error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.randomizerwadds, PID: 15750
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException
I'm quite sure that I am adding the right dependencies, meta-data and app-ID.
Does anyone have experience with this?

Does this answer your question? Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException
